# How to wrap specific xml elements in another element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
Folks! there is an xml input , 
<a>sample</a>
<a>dummy</a>
<a>text</a>
<b>data1</b>
<b>data2</b>
<a>sample2</a>
<a>sample3</a>
Here requirement is to wrap all <a> elements in another wrapper, here expected output should look like
<wrap>
<a>
<a>
<a>
</wrap>
<b>
<b>
<wrap>
<a>
<a>
</wrap>
```

the output should look like above.
i have tried some approaches but couldnt wrap , the same elements sequentially.
here element a , has to be wrapped by wrap element when , xml processing encounters element b, the wrapper should close and when a element again comes then again wrap wrapper should open

Comment: Your "xml input" is not XML because it does not have a single root element.  Moreover, this is not a code-writing service, so you're expected to show an effort solving your problem first and only then ask about a specific problem you're having.  Being stuck before you start means you're not ready to ask here.

Comment: This is basically a grouping question. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.